# Store Data Using Session Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, session, dom, session-cookies

I'm supposed to click on a button, then it will redirect to a form page and fill up a particular details. I must obtain this data and store it locally using session objects.

## Button code:

```
<form action="Enquiry.html" method="get">
  <button class="button1" id="CreamLx">Book Now!</button>
</form>
```

## Form Page:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form1">
 <p>
   <label for="Products">Products</label>
 </p>
 <select name="Products" id="Products" required="required">
   <option value="">Please Select</option>
   <option value="Cream1">Creamy</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

## JavaScript code:

```
   "use strict";
    function validate(){
    var errMsg = "";                    // stores the error message 
    var result = true;                  // assumes no errors 

    if (result){
             storeProduct(CreamLx);
            }

    return result; 
    }

    function storeProduct(CreamLx){
         sessionStorage.CreamLx= CreamLx;

     }

    function getProduct(CreamLx){

      if(sessionStorage.CreamLx!= undefined){

       document.getElementById("CreamLx").textContent = sessionStorage.CreamLx;

       document.getElementById("CreamLx").value = sessionStorage.CreamLx;

     }

   }

  function init (){
       var car=document.getElementById("car");
       var option = document.getElementById('Products').value = product;
      }


   window.onload = init;
```

Where did I go wrong? My JavaScript is not working.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I don't see  `validate()` being called. What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: basically all i need to do is , when click on the button it will automatically select this <option value="Cream1">Creamy</option> in the form page.I need to store the information and retrive the information using session storage.

Comment: There is no "session storage" in javascript. Do you mean `localStorage`?

Comment: ya, because my assignment requirement is  You will need to use JavaScript to obtain this data
and store it locally using either session objects or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Session storage is all Server side. Javascript is Client side, so you will need to run a php script from your javascript that will set and get session variables.